# I can't find NDK in my SDK Manager on Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to download the NDK in the SDK Manager, but I can't find it. My SDK Manager is different from others, can somebody show me where it is exactly?
[image]

Comment: instead of waiting for an answer install it from a zip file: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html, more [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html)

Comment: i think google is deprecating the old standalone sdk manager. You will find the ndk in the new sdk manager inside android studio, in the link mentioned above

Comment: thanks for sharing this link,i will try to download it, thank you

Comment: @nandsito that one is broken for me

Comment: @James_Parsons which one? both work here

Comment: @nandsito The Android Studio one, it appears the UI is disabled for it.

Comment: @James_Parsons sorry, i didn't get your problem. Maybe you should open a question